# iPhone framework paths?

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I recently moved my projects to a new mac, along with a newer version of Xcode.

When i opened my project i noticed that some files were red. So i remapped them by setting the path (by project path) and then providing the proper path location.

Now my problem is that the frameworks that i have are red, and i cant find their location! I did set the framework paths to be "relative to current SDK" however.

Can anybody help me get my frameworks mapped correctly?
The frameworks im using are:
- QuartzCore.framework
- libsqlite3.0.dylib
- UIKit.framework
- Foundation.frameowrk
- CoreGraphics.framework

The XCode version is 3.1.4 (the only one installed).
The iPhone app was originally created using a prior version of Xcode (i dont remember which version).

---

I still dont have an answer. Im going deeper into this mess of a problem that Apple created.
In all my .m files im importing

How can i add this UIKit framework to my project Target with respect to the current SDK?
In fact, forget about the ref w/ respect to the SDK, let's just get the framework from the 3.0 SDK as a referenced framework. Right now when i reference it is red.

Note: references related to frameworks, everything about it, is driving me insane, and making me more frustrated at apple for this sloppiness, more than ever.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double click on your target to bring up the info pane you will see a tab labeled "Linked Libraries".  From here you can click the plus button to add the libraries and xcode will do the right thing when you add the desired frameworks

Comment: double click on the target?
You mean 'Targets'?
When i double click on it, it does nothing.

Comment: no, expand the "Targets" folder and you will see a file inside.  Double click this.

Comment: Cool. I found the Linked Libraries under the General tab.
BUT, i cant find the UIKit.framework or the CoreGraphics.framework.

Also, will adding framework via this method allow for building between iphone device and iphone simulator without changing the frameworks mnually?

Comment: I dont get it. When i add a framework (via + from Linked Libraries list) the framework gets added to the project root, instead of the Frameworks folder.

Right now my Frameworks folder as the aforementioned frameworks in it (all red). Also, when i add a framework, it is STILL red.

Why does this have to be rocket science?!!?!?

Comment: When i add a framework it gets set to "Relative to Current SDK", which seems correct.
The path automatically gets set to System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework.

BUT, the Full Path gets set to the xcode project folder .../System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework, which is TOTALLY WRONG!

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly this problem. Somehow 'Base SDK' in Build Settings of a project was set to Mac OS X after I have installed Xcode 4.2.

Click on your project, change Base SDK to 'Latest iOS' and enjoy the vibe.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with red frameworks and bad pathing.  If you're getting an error that says, "Base SDK Missing" you'll need to Get Info on your Xcode Project and check that it can find the right SDK.

Near the bottom of the General Info tab there will be an option Base SDK for All Configurations.  Select a different SDK and see if that helps.

I ran into issues when I upgraded to a beta SDK and it was loading up deprecated frameworks from an old SDK.